# Web services: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservices-client

I'm trying to set up a website(ASP.net in c#). As a part of this, First I'm trying to set it up on my windows 7 station.
The website also has web services layer.
I'm hosting the website on  local IIS 7.5.
Web services are where the data is fetched from( the data base is on another server. MySQl is used).
When I browse the site, I can browse until, I hit web services.
Then I get this error" **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:63479"**

This website was not coded by me. I was asked to host it on a different server.
Please help me set up this application.Can you help me listing down the the steps to test it?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: whats the web service you are talking about? web api ?

Comment: Yes, it is a web Api. Im able to browse the directory of just the web services.

Comment: depending on whether the web api is a separate service or not, you might need to deploy both the website and the api